# Height of html is not 100% of window on browser resize

Tags: html, css

[image]

This happens when I resize my window. Anyone know how to make the html fill the browser window??

Comment: `height: 100vh`

Comment: a bit of code snipped would be always helpful to debug any issues.

Comment: Is your `body` 100% height of the `html`?

Comment: @Huangism Yes it is.

Comment: @senojoeht That doesn't do anything

Comment: We need to see your code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well then you will need to post some code to reproduce the issue, maybe there is a max-height set somewhere or something, no way to tell like this

Answer (score 0):

Try `height: 100vh`

See documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

Comment: Doesn't work. I have both body and html at 100% height